# How to unblock traffic from a country in google cloud platform

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform

I created a wordpress website on google cloud platform.
I bought my domain from google domains.

But people in some countries cannot access my website, they have to use VPN.
Is there any way to unblock that countries?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way to unblock traffic. It's not a Google's decision, but US government'.

Comment: For more information have a look at the documentation [Google Cloud Platform Territory List](https://cloud.google.com/gcp-territory-list) and [Countries or regions where Google Workspace is available](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2891389).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Unfortunately there's no way to unblock traffic*. It's not a Google's decision, but US government'. For more information have a look at the documentation [Google Cloud Platform Territory List](https://cloud.google.com/gcp-territory-list) and Countries or regions where [Google Workspace is available](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2891389). As a result, VPN is the only option.